# what does `x` mean in PIC opcode format?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I hope this is right place to ask
In PIC mid-range micro controller instruction set
I found this strange formatted op code for the instruction

`CLRW  00010xxxxxxx`
It doesn't make any sense what these x(s) refer to ?

Comment: Did you read the rest of the section?

Comment: yup I couldn't find any thing regard that  x

Comment: CLRW:Clear W
Syntax: [ label ] CLRW
Operands: None
Operation: 00h → W
                    1 → Z
Status Affected: Z
Encoding:
0000010xxxxxxx
Description: W register is cleared. Zero bit (Z) is set.
Words: 1
Cycles: 1
Example 1
CLRW
Before Instruction
W=0x5A
After Instruction
W=0x00
Z=1

Comment: that is all what they said

Comment: A little more context would be valuable. What is the paragraph about where you found this? What doe the lines before and after this one look like?

Comment: well it is the table of instruction set provided by microchip here http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31029a.pdf

Comment: table 29.1 page 29-3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'x' means 'does not matter.' Those are the bits of the "CLRW" instruction.

When you type "CLRW" into an .asm file and assemble it, this opcode gets converted to '00010xxxxxxx' (12 bits, since this particular PIC architecture is 12-bit.) It doesn't matter what the x's are; if the PIC executes anything with the first bits as shown, it will be treated as a CLRW instruction.

Comment: Interesting! Sounds like pretty bad design. They're wasting a lot of possible future instructions by not forcing the extra bits to '0' and reserving the other opcodes for future use, even if they don't decode them in every chip.

Comment: Well one of the design "benefits" of thier 12-bit core devices is that they only have 35 or so instructions. It is a [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller) architecture - reduced instruction set computing. So they wouldn't add more instructions. (This was one of the reasons I experimented with PIC assembler - with only 35 instructions, how hard could it be? Hahaha... now I use C.) :)

Comment: its not a waste if you have to make the chip larger or more complicated or consume more power.  Just because you CAN invent more instructions doesnt mean you should.   Another way to look at this and this has been repeated on so many processors, these dont cares are an opportunity for future expansion.  again most popular instruction sets this what happened

Comment: @dwelch You don't have to make the chip larger to add a "reserved for future expansion" in the datasheet. PIC already have a lot of crazy instructions, it's not really the "lean and mean" machine you seem to think of. :)

Comment: @pipe, which instructions are crazy?

Comment: @chu For example _RETLW_ and the extremely specialized _CLRWDT_.

Comment: @pipe RETLW is pretty useful for look-up tables, matrix keyboard decoding ... and what's the problem with clrwdt?

Comment: @Chu Just saying that it's laughable to say "Just because you CAN invent more instructions doesnt mean you should" in the context of a PIC, considering that's exactly what they have done. RETLW is of course useful, but so are a lot of other instructions that could have taken its place. CLRWDT shouldn't even be an instruction, not sure what they were thinking there.

Comment: @pipe, re clrwdt, how else would you trap stuck-in-loop errors? And what could replace RETLW?

Comment: @Chu Every other microcontroller that I know of implements this as a sequence of writes to an internal register.

Comment: @pipe, a single instruction is better, surely